# how to ckeck a number is between 1 and N

Tags: java, duplicates, range, permutation

I want to check weather a tab of int[] is a permutation or not , meaning 3 caracteristics :

First, no duplicates

Second, the range of numbers should be between 1 and N(size)

Last, all numbers between 1 and N sould appear in the permutation

For exemple 2 2 3 is not a permutation because 2 is a duplicate , 2 3 4 is not a permutation because 4>N=3 ,and also because the number 1 is missing ...

so far I fixed the duplicates and range problem, but I still need to force all numbers between 1 and N to appear in the permutation , here is the code so far :

```
   public  static boolean isperm(byte[] tab){

  for (int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){

    if (tab[i]>=1 && tab[i]<=tab.length ) {
       for (int j=0;j<tab.length;j++) {
          for (int k=j+1;k<tab.length;k++) {
               if (tab[k]==tab[j]){ // or use .equals()
                      return false;
          }
       }
    }
       return true;          
    } else {
       return false; 
    }
  }
return false; 
}
```

so my Question is a test to verify all numbers between 1 and N exist in the int[]

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using. Also, please fix your horrific indentation; it's hurting my eyes.

Comment: I hope that's better now

Comment: I must ask, is that how your source code files actually look?

Comment: I think u should ckeck ur eyes out my friend

Comment: I think you should check out your monitor. [This is how it looks](http://imgur.com/IPcbXsh). It's a fixed-width font, so I doubt we're seeing different things.

Answer (score 2):

Can I offer a different solution?

Try to make a boolean array in the size of `tab.length`, with each column represent a number that should be in the permutation. now in your loops, check if the number is already marked in the temp array and if its on the right size.

This way, you can verify that all the numbers are from 1 to N + no duplicates.
In the end, just check if all the array is marked, and you had check everything.

Good luck.

Comment: this sounds good. two passes on the bool array and your done. (one to set to true when a number x is found, and the second to make sure none are still false). quick and simple

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all three required characteristics can be verified by:

(1) Sorting the int array
(2) Iterating the array and making sure all items from 1 to len(int array) exist

I am not going to provide any pseudo code as this looks suspiciously like home work.

Answer (score 0):

This should be it

```
boolean isPermutation(int[] a, int n) {
if (a.length != n) {
        return false;
    }
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[i + 1] - 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
     }
```